# How can I check the layers display using the vctr-file in Cesium SandCastle

Tags: cesiumjs

Is there any way to drop the vctr-file in the Cesium SandCastle just to take a look the tile is n't corrupted. I mean, after i checked a bunch of tiles on the map, i've found that some tiles are glitched or smth - part of them wasn't draw correctly and just 'located' over each other I think. I need to check if it is so, so i'm looking for a way to glance on the mapping of the polygons in this tile.

Actually I am zero in Cesium. I need to check tile display and all  I have is the bunch of vctr-files
I've noticed that there is "region" attribute in the file, but I don't know how to rework it for the Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray (if it is what i need)